# console.log not rendering inside variable

Tags: javascript, console.log

I have created  var template but when I console.log in chrome console nothing shows up. I am a little confused because if I remove the `console.log('template created')`; and move it above  the `var template = function()` it renders in the console

```
    var Template = function(){
      // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
      this.__construct  = function(){    
          console.log('template created');
      };
      // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
      //works in console


      console.log('template created');

      var Template = function(){

      // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
      this.__construct  = function(){

      };
      //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
   };
```

Comment: Have you executed the function ?

Comment: Are you using a JavaScript library? `__construct` has no special meaning in JavaScript. Therefore, you have to execute the function for it work.

Comment: this is what i have here but its from a 2013 tutorial so i dont know if its changed  but i cant see it being changed 

var Template = function(){
   
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  this.__construct  = function(){
      
       console.log('template created');
  };
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  };

Comment: If you do `Template.__construct()` it should log to the console. I think you are expecting it to automatically work when you construct the Template object, which is not the case. JavaScript has no notion of `__construct` as I've stated that's a PHP thing I believe. Also, the `//` characters indicate a comment so they are not necessary. Can you place the link to the tutorial?

Comment: https://jream.com/dashboard/course/view/2/74

its a payed tutorial so i dont think you will get access but it was on youtube until the guy put copyright claim in youtube ...

Comment: also the comments were code seperators now i see the display didnt come out on posting here

Answer (score 4):

Are you expecting the `console.log` in `__construct` to fire? Cause it won't. What you're doing with

```
  this.__construct  = function(){    
      console.log('template created');
  };
```

is creating a function on a new object ( if you're using `Template` as a function constructor, i.e. `new Template()` ). What you end up with is a new object with the function `__construct`.  I.e.

```
var Template = function(){
  console.log('fires when initialized');

  this.__construct = function () {
    console.log('inside construct');
  };
};

var template = new Template(); // 'fires when initialized'
template.__construct(); // 'inside construct'
```

It's not recommended to create functions on objects in this fashion. You'd typically want to place these functions on the prototype. I recommend reading up on `function constructors` for a deeper understanding. http://tobyho.com/2010/11/22/javascript-constructors-and/ seems like a good place to start.

Comment: you see that works fine your code Template = new template() is what i want to achieve  the tutorial  i am following is videos from 2013 i think

there code works in video with

var Template = function() {

this.__construct = function() {

console.log('Template created');

};
};

thanks i will work along with what you provided